# Ruby rest-client "Accept" Header issue

Tags: ruby, rest, header, rest-client

I was experimenting with the Ruby [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem and ran into an "issue" so to speak. I noticed when I would hit a certain URL that should just return HTML, I would get a 404 error unless I specifically specified:

```
RestClient.get('http://www.example.com/path/path', accept: 'text/html')
```

However, pretty much any other page that I would hit **without** specifying the `Accept` header explicitly would return HTML just fine.

I looked at the source for the `Request` object located [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb) and in the `default_headers` method around line 486 it appears that the default `Accept` header is `*/*`. I also found the relevant pull request [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/pull/323).

I'm not quite sure why on a particular site (not all) I have to explicitly specify `Accept: text/html` when any other site that returns HTML by default does it without any extra work. I should note that other pages on this same site work fine when requesting the page without explicitly specifying `text/html`.

It's not a huge issue and I can easily work around it using `text/html` but I just thought it was a bit odd.

I should **also** note that when I use another REST client, such as IntelliJ's built-in one and specify `Accept: */*` it returns HTML no problem...

EDIT: Ok, this is a bit strange...when I do this:

```
RestClient.get('http://www.example.com/path/path', accept: '*/*')
```

Then it returns HTML as I expect it to but leaving off that `accept: */*` parameter doesn't work even though by default that header should be `*/*` according to the source code...

I wonder if because my URL has `/path/path` in it, RestClient thinks it's an endpoint to some API so it tries to retrieve XML instead...

EDIT 2: Doing a bit more experimenting...I was able to pass a block to the GET request as follows:

```
RestClient.get('http://example.com/path/path') {
    |response, request, result|

    puts response.code
    puts request.processed_headers
}
```

And I get a `404` error and the `processed_headers` returns:

```
{"Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"}
```

The response body is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <errors>Not Found</errors>
</hash>
```

So, it *is* sending a `*/*` header but for some reason it looks like the `application/xml` gets priority. Maybe this is just something on the server-side and out of my control? I guess I'm just not sure how that `application/xml` is even being added into the `Accept` header. I can't find anything skimming through the source code.

Comment: can you tell what's the error code for that particular request?

Comment: Yeah, it's giving me a 404. I was able to pass a block to the GET request and the Accept header it is sending in is: `{"Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml"` ... If I explicitly tell it to only accept `*/*` it works as I mentioned in my edit, I'm not quite sure why the XML takes priority when on other pages on the same site the same header (or lack thereof) works fine...

Comment: The more specific fields are given more priority than those with a range of possibilities.So here `xml/application` is getting more priority. You can study more about accept [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: @r2_d2 Makes sense, I'm just unsure how exactly that `application/xml` field is even being put into the `Accept` header...I can't find it anywhere in the source. From what I'm seeing it should just be `*/*` but somewhere along the way `q=0.5, application/xml` is being appended.

Comment: but the rest-client is sending this header for some reason. Where does the url point to?

Comment: @r2_d2 It just points to a regular website. No odd API endpoints or anything. I opened an issue on Github about this. That PR I linked should have fixed this and according to the source on Github it should just pass `*/*` but for some reason mine seems to have the old behavior even though I'm on the current gem. Maybe I'm just missing something really obvious here...

Comment: what do you mean by old behavior?

Comment: @r2_d2 The old behavior was sending `*/*;q=0.5 application/xml` in the Accept header. Someone did a PR that changed it to just be `*/*`. I actually figured out the problem. I installed a release candidate version (2.0.0rc2) and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the "problem". It looks like the PR I mentioned in my original post wasn't actually released until `rest-client2.0.0.rc1` which is still a release candidate so it isn't actually out yet or at least obtainable via my `gem update rest-client`.

I used the following command to install `2.0.0rc2`:

```
gem install rest-client -v 2.0.0.rc2 --pre
```

Then referenced it in my code and it works now:

```
@request = RestClient::Request.new(:method => :get, :url => 'http://some/resource')
puts @request.default_headers[:accept]
```

Prints...

```
*/*
```

As expected now.